# Validating application of -bind_at_load on OS X

Tags: macos, linker, dyld

I have a binary that I have linked with the -bind_at_load argument to ld. On an ELF system, I'd use -Wl,-z,now and then readelf to verify that the DT_BIND_NOW flag was enabled on the binary. On OS X, how can I verify that the the appropriate flag in the mach header has been ste to honor -bind_at_load? What is the name of the flag, and what value should it be set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `otool -l /path/to/binary` and inspect the `LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY` load command. If the binary was linked with `-bind_at_load`, then the lazy bind offset/size are equal to 0: `dyld` won’t lazily bind symbols and all symbols are bound when the binary is loaded.

Sample output:

- With `-bind_at_load`

  ```
  Load command 4
              cmd LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY
          cmdsize 48
       rebase_off 8192
      rebase_size 8
         bind_off 8200
        bind_size 224
    weak_bind_off 0
   weak_bind_size 0
    lazy_bind_off 0
   lazy_bind_size 0
       export_off 8424
      export_size 48
  ```
- Without `-bind_at_load`

  ```
  Load command 4
              cmd LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY
          cmdsize 48
       rebase_off 8192
      rebase_size 8
         bind_off 8200
        bind_size 128
    weak_bind_off 0
   weak_bind_size 0
    lazy_bind_off 8328
   lazy_bind_size 104
       export_off 8432
      export_size 48
  ```

Comment: I read the source code and it seems that `otool -hv` should print `BINDATLOAD` when the corresponding flag on the Mach-O header is set, but it doesn’t in my tests. I’ll take a look at this later.

Comment: Oddly, my binaries always seem to have 0 for the two lazy_bind fields, regardless of whether I use -bind_at-load. I'll also investigate more, but thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: Ah, never mind. User error. The values do change when I alter bind_at_load. This looks promising.

Comment: @acm `dyld` completely ignores the header flag, so I think it’s safe to infer bind_at_load from lazy binding offset & size (well, size > 0 alone suffices). See  the conversation at https://twitter.com/bavarious/status/345609282085072897